# Get right label using indices?

Tags: python

Really stupid question as I am new to python:

If I have labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 
and indics = [2, 3, 0, 1]

How should I get the corresponding label using each index so I can get: ['c', 'd', 'a', 'b']?

Comment: These are plain Python lists, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few alternatives, one, is to use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
indices = [2, 3, 0, 1]

result = [labels[i] for i in indices]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['c', 'd', 'a', 'b']
```

Basically iterate over each index and fetch the item at that position. The above is equivalent to the following for loop:

```
result = []
for i in indices:
   result.append(labels[i])
```

A third option is to use [operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter

labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
indices = [2, 3, 0, 1]

result = list(itemgetter(*indices)(labels))
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['c', 'd', 'a', 'b']
```